# yaml key value pair with dollar syntax

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I saw a code which is present in a Spring boot application's yaml file

```
task:
  follow: ${name:Rohit}
```

I know `task.follow` is the key but didn't understand `${name:Rohit}`. What does it refer to and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the key `task.follow` should take the value from Environment Property `name`, but if it was not defined while your spring boot app starts up, then it will take the default value `Robit`.